# Temperature question

Tags: pi-4

i'm planning to buy an Raspberry Pi 4 Model B. Short time after release of the Pi 4 many people have complained about heat problems (not only at 100% CPU usage, but in idle). My question is now, did the firmware updates from the past fix these heat problems especially the ones which happened in idle?

Comment: When I bought a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B, I also ordered a [Pimoroni Fan Shim](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/fan-shim). Ambient in the room is around 18 C and it idles and runs light tasks at about 35 C. Tor proxy, Deluge, Samba. If I load it up it will go up to around 55 C. If the fan is shut down, it idles around 55 and can go to 75 - 80 on load. The Fan Shim cost 9.60 UK pounds. I have all firmware updates.

Answer (score 4):

As of this moment the temperature of my Pi, which is up to date, is idle by 58°C and under constant load of 50% CPU utilization by 70°C. I use little heat sinks on the CPU and the voltage regulator.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using it with Raspbian Buster with Desktop and few scripts are running on startup. I2C and SPI both are running continuously and a graphical python script too. Then its temperature goes to ~60 degrees when room temperature is 27-28 degrees.

Answer (score 3):

Don't expect there to be a firmware fix for the RPi 4 heat dissipation. That's the way the chip is built: if you want more performance, you need more current and there will be more heat. All single-board computers similar to RPi 4 in terms of performace (Orange Pi PC, Odroid, etc.) need heat sinks or cooler fans, and will go into thermal throttling without cooling.

Practically, RPi 4 is only usable without additional cooling if it sits idle most of the time. Even then, a passive heat sink on the SoC is recommended: the SoC will be substantially cooler and will be able to perform typical tasks like an upgrade without slowing down to a crawl. However, if you plan to load more than 1 CPU core for long periods of time, you will have to install active cooling, i.e. a heat sink and a fan.

Comment: I agree with most of what you've said here, but unless I miss a subtle point [*The Organization* did announce a firmware fix](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=243500&p=1490467&hilit=vl805#p1490467) for the USB3 host adapter that "should save about 300mW". On my system at least, it was apparently applied as part of a routine `upgrade`; verified by `sudo rpi-eeprom-update`. Has it made any difference? I don't know when it was applied, but my temp logs began on Dec 30 (a few days after it went "online") & they show no notable diffs.

Comment: @Seamus Thanks for the comment, 300mW looks great. Still, it's only about 5% of the total power budget so it won't change the fact that Pi 4 needs cooling.